# Function not working

Tags: jquery, function, jquery-mobile

I am prototyping a web app idea i have
I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SM5QJ/) set up to show you. (crude prototype)

Two of my functions work perfect.

However once the options appear the next function doesn't work when called..

Perhaps i am being blind? i have had a 8hour coding session today.

But once an option is selected the container holding the options should disappear

```
function begin(){
$( this ).hide();
    $(".center-logo").hide(),
    $(".clapper").show(),
    $(".clapper").text("tap to chose option")
}
function movieChoice(){
    $("#film-list").fadeIn('slow'),
    $(movieList.movies).each(function(index){$("#movies").append('<li class="selector" id="'+this.rating+'">' + this.name  + '</li>');});
}
function movieSelector(){
    $("#film-list").fadeOut('slow')
    $(".clapper").hide()
    $(".date").show()
}

$("#begin").on( "swiperight", begin)
$(".clapper").on( "tap", movieChoice)
$(".selector").on( "tap", movieSelector)
```

Comment: You're using commas where I think you mean to be using semi-colons and not using line delimiters at all in same situation. I'd take care of those inconsistencies and see what happens.

Comment: Btw, it is clearly written in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (in bold!): *"Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`."*

Comment: You probably want to read this about event delegation: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this

```
$(".selector").on( "tap", movieSelector)
```

to

```
$("#movies").on("tap", ".selector", movieSelector)
```

and you're good to go. Your code doesnt work because at the time you bind `selector` with `movieSelector()`, its not yet available. This should fix that, because `movies` is available when the DOM is `ready`. There's also another way. Instead of binding `tap` to closest static parent (in this case its `movies`), you could *also* bind it to `document`.

```
$(document).on("tap", ".selector", movieSelector)
```

There are two more things wrong with your code :

1. You are using `ready` event to do all this. Consider using a page event such `pageinit` or `pageshow` to bind your data/ init stuff etc. But since youy dont even have `data-role=page` in your code, I suggest you remove the jQM tag from your question.
2. Also, you're using a lot of `,` instead of `;`. You might want to change that.

Comment: Thanks this all makes sense, very simple really, ill put it down to an 8 hour coding session earlier

Answer (score 1):

You need to lissen on #movies

```
$("#movies").on( "tap", '.selector', movieSelector)
```

Check here http://jsfiddle.net/SM5QJ/3/

The problem is that you bind it to an element thats not exist in the dom.
So what you can do is to bind it to #movies and tell it to lissen on tap event on .selector
doing it on this way will keep it updated on appended items to the dom.

You can read more about it here http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Code without explanation is almost always useless.

Comment: This works, but i agree, could you explain why?

Comment: I have updated my answer. But i rly recomend that you read the api documentation. http://api.jquery.com/on/